Stripe: Azure does not install all files
I am trying to run a task on my minimal API in Azure and while it works fine in the local environment azure is not letting it to run:
this is the whole task:
 public static async Task<ActionResult<string>> StartKYC(string accountid, string? link = "https://www.example.com/en/kyc/end")
        {

            try
            {

                StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("stripe_sand");
                var options2 = new AccountLinkCreateOptions
                {
                    Account = accountid,
                    RefreshUrl = "https://www.example.com/en/pharmux/kyc/end",
                    ReturnUrl = "https://www.example.com/en/pharmux/kyc/end",
                    Type = "account_onboarding",
                    CollectionOptions = new AccountLinkCollectionOptionsOptions
                    {
                        Fields = "eventually_due",
                        FutureRequirements = "include"
                    },
                };
                var service2 = new AccountLinkService();

                AccountLink accountLink = service2.Create(options2);
                Console.WriteLine("test2");

                return new ActionResult<string>(accountLink.Url);
            }
            catch (StripeException e)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(e.StripeError.Message);
            }
        }

and I get this error:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
2024-04-06T15:08:15.8584214Z       Connection id "0HN2M9CR0BJ9E", Request id "0HN2M9CR0BJ9E:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
2024-04-06T15:08:15.9082605Z       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
2024-04-06T15:08:15.9272081Z
2024-04-06T15:08:15.9388722Z       File name: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
2024-04-06T15:08:15.9578947Z          at Stripe.StripeConfiguration.get_ApiKey()
2024-04-06T15:08:15.9773705Z          at Stripe.StripeConfiguration.BuildDefaultStripeClient() in /_/src/Stripe.net/Infrastructure/Public/StripeConfiguration.cs:line 230
2024-04-06T15:08:15.9881449Z          at Stripe.StripeConfiguration.get_StripeClient() in /_/src/Stripe.net/Infrastructure/Public/StripeConfiguration.cs:line 161
2024-04-06T15:08:16.0067122Z          at Stripe.Service`1.get_Client() in /_/src/Stripe.net/Services/_base/Service.cs:line 56
2024-04-06T15:08:16.0085353Z          at Stripe.Service`1.get_BaseUrl() in /_/src/Stripe.net/Services/_base/Service.cs:line 43
2024-04-06T15:08:16.0282524Z          at Stripe.Service`1.SetupRequestOptions(RequestOptions requestOptions) in /_/src/Stripe.net/Services/_base/Service.cs:line 578
2024-04-06T15:08:16.0586286Z          at Stripe.Service`1.RequestAsync[T](HttpMethod method, String path, BaseOptions options, RequestOptions requestOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Stripe.net/Services/_base/Service.cs:line 275
2024-04-06T15:08:16.0775491Z          at Stripe.Service`1.Request[T](HttpMethod method, String path, BaseOptions options, RequestOptions requestOptions) in /_/src/Stripe.net/Services/_base/Service.cs:line 253
2024-04-06T15:08:16.0786470Z          at Stripe.AccountLinkService.Create(AccountLinkCreateOptions options, RequestOptions requestOptions) in /_/src/Stripe.net/Services/AccountLinks/AccountLinkService.cs:line 27
2024-04-06T15:08:16.0793751Z          at fhirServer.PaymentEndpoints.StartKYC(String accountid, String link) in /Users/pedrospecter/Downloads/work/datacrio/fhir-server/classes/stripe.cs:line 480

I thought initially that would be a problem with the API key but the same runs just fine in other methods calling stripe. Any one has a fix?

This looks like a common issue for Azure. I'd recommend trying to update "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version to 4.7.0 and any other lower version as suggested here

@yuting thank you for that but not really feasible. Actually, I quite did a workaround, (not a fix but a work around). I just created a new Project and copied all the functional code, and reinstalled the libraries. As soon as I deployed, working like a charm. I think there was something wrong with my project.
